# Accessing method on self from init?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a singleton that I have setup that I am using to both preload and access my audio files (both sfx and music) I started out running `[[FGAudio sharedInstance] preload];` from the AppDelegate but was concerned about having to remember to call preload before using the singleton. My question is to make things automatic, can I access a method on the singleton to do my setup and preload in init, or is it not wise to access a method init as things are still starting up?

```
+ (FGAudio *)sharedInstance {
    static FGAudio *sharedAudio = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedAudio = [[FGAudio alloc]init];
    });
    return sharedAudio;
}
```

.

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        [self preload];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
+ (FGAudio *)sharedInstance {
    static FGAudio *sharedAudio = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedAudio = [[FGAudio alloc]init];
        [sharedAudio preload];
    });
    return sharedAudio;
}
```

Referencing the method from `init` isn't bad if you can guarantee that subclasses won't mess with it or the objects it relies upon and in the future you won't mess up the preloading period by requiring objects that get inited after you call preload. If you use the above snippet you don't even have to worry about any of that and you also get a preloaded singleton.

Comment: Much appreciated Joel, thats actually what I had in the first place :) It just struck me that without this it was possible to create an un-preloaded singleton. Not that I am going to do that as this is personal code, but it just felt wrong. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Just as a side note for anyone who might come across this answer in future I also added [FGAudio sharedInstance]; to the AppDelegate method application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: just to make sure that the singleton is setup and preloaded when the application starts.

Answer (score 1):

[Calling a method from the init method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289417/calling-a-method-from-the-init-method)

"Yes. Just be very careful (your object may not have been fully initialised, it shouldn't use accessor methods so as to comply with the previous restriction, et cetera)"